# MySQL query to assign a unique random number to each row

Tags: mysql, random

I wish to attach a column to my table which will be a random number from a sequential list = to the number of rows.

So, if my table had **999 rows**, then **the numbers 1 to 999 would be assigned randomly and uniquely**.

Now, I figured that I could add a dummy TempRandomColumn=Rand(), sort by that and add the numbers sequentially using PHP. But that means 999 MySQL statements.

Is there a way to do this using a single MySQL statement?

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
SET @r := 0;
UPDATE  items2
SET     author_id = (@r := @r + 1)
ORDER BY
        RAND()
```

Comment: Can you really order by rand?  That seems weird to me, because doesn't that mean it would have to call "rand" on a row every time it compared it to another row?

Comment: It first selects RAND()s as temporary values along with normal records, then sorts on these temporary values. It's same as SELECT * FROM (SELECT id, RAND() AS rnd FROM table) ORDER BY rnd

Answer (score 1):

```
SET @i=1;
SELECT t.*, @i:=@i+1 as RAND_NUM FROM your_table t ORDER BY RAND();
```