# Assign a random value to a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got following tables:

table 1:

```
+-----------+-------------+
| record_id | record_name |
+-----------+-------------+
| 0         | 'test'      |
| 1         | 'test1'     |
| 5         | 'mytest'    |
| 8         | 'ultratest' |
| ....      | ....        |
+-----------+-------------+
```

table 2:

```
+---------+-----------+
| user_id | record_id |
+---------+-----------+
| 1       | 0         |
| 2       | 0         |
| 3       | 0         |
| 4       | 0         |
| ....    | ....      |
+---------+-----------+
```

I want to assign each row of the table 2 a random record_id from the ids, present in the table 1 (0,1,5,8); the ids don't have to be unique.

I've read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602952/mysql-query-to-assign-a-unique-random-number-to-each-row), and it's no good for this case because the numbers assigned there are sequential

How do I do that with mysql?

Answer (score 0):

From mysql documentation

To obtain a random integer `R` in the range `i <= R < j`, use the expression `FLOOR(i + RAND() * (j – i))`. For example, to obtain a random integer in the range the range `7 <= R < 12`, you could use the following statement:

```
SELECT FLOOR(7 + (RAND() * 5));
```

Comment: You might run into a small problem here. Let's say after you generate the a random number, that said number may **not** be a valid number inside table 1 (although it is within range). You need to worry about that edge case.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t2.user_id, t1.record_id 
from 
    t2
    inner join (
        select record_id
        from t1
        order by rand()
    ) t1 on 1 = 1
group by t2.user_id
```

Comment: IMHO there should be a `limit 1` or a `top 1` in the record_id subquery.