# Group entries into random groups of 5 by inserting random numbers into mysql table using php

Tags: php, mysql, random

I have a MySQL table with columns including id, names of people and a random number. What I would like to do is every week, collect the names into random groups of 5 each. It's for 5 aside football tournaments and it's getting too big to do it by hand now and I'd like it to be automatic.

The way I think it'll work will be to get the num_rows, divide by 5 to get the total number of groups ($divide). Then make a loop where 5 rows are selected at random and a random number between 1 and $divide is given to them. It's got to change every week so it can't be a one off task. I'd also like it to accommodate situations where the num_rows doesn't exactly divide by 5 and creates a last group of the remaining number.

This is as far as I've got -

```
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($data);

$divide = $num_rows / 5;

$rannum = RAND (1, $divide);

$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE allpeep SET rannumber = $rannum")
or die(mysql_error());
```

but as you may have guessed, this just inserts the same random number into all the rows. I *think* this requires a while loop, but I can't quite work out how it'll work.

Comment: I'd argue a new approach here.  How do you know that in a large dataset a random number selected isn't going to be duplicated?

Comment: Hi Chris, yes that's a consideration, which is why I think it will need a while loop...perhaps even an array based on the first random number - but if you can think of a new approach then i'm all ears.

Comment: **WARNING**: `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications as it's being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices.

Comment: Thanks Tadman, can you show me this as a working solution to my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5
```

But this still isn't going to protect from duplicate if multiple queries are made, so ...

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY RAND()
```

Get the whole set, then parse into 5's in your server script.  I'm assuming you want these static until next week, so for each 5 set update the sql server telling them what 'group' they are in this week.

In the alternative, you could use the former syntax if you use a seed for the rand() function.  Using the  year/week of year combination will give you a reproducable rand sequence

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY RAND(YEARWEEK(CURDATE()))
```

Then you avoid having to update anything on the server, and only have to output the results

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {tablename} ORDER BY RAND(YEARWEEK(CURDATE()))")
or die(mysql_error());

$group = 1;
$row = true;
while ($row) {
  echo "Group $group";
  for ($i=0; $group++, $i<5 && $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result); $i++) {
    // output current row
    echo "team $row['team']";
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Chris, I think the top solution sounds very promising, but would be something new to me in terms of parsing into a group and updating the table - would you be able to point me towards an existing answer or tutorial for a hand? Cheers for your help so far.

Comment: Updated the answer so you can see how to spin through results to display the 5 sets

Comment: That's good stuff, thanks Chris, I'm happy with that result, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a similar thread that should help you. [Assign a Unique Random Number to Each Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602952/mysql-query-to-assign-a-unique-random-number-to-each-row)

If you setup a script to run this query, you can run it using a cronjob anytime you want.