# SQL update using PHP for loop takes too long

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

I am trying to UPDATE my table using a PHP for loop but it will take too long to work. I really have `200,000` people in my table. When I open the php file, the browser literally hungs itself :) When I open the phpMyAdmin, I can see it works, yet very slowly.

Is there a way to do the exact same thing using SQL, directly in phpMyAdmin?

```
for ($a = 0; $a < 200000; $a++) {
    $rand = mt_rand(10000000, 99999999);
    // checks whether the same url exists or not
    $sec = "SELECT person_url FROM person WHERE person_url = '$rand'";
    $result = $sqli->query($sec);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $finish = $row['person_url'];
    if ($finish == false) {
        $sql = $sqli->prepare("UPDATE person SET person_url = '$rand' WHERE person_id = '$a'");
        $sql->execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should only prepare the statement once, then execute it in the loop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL query to assign a unique random number to each row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602952/mysql-query-to-assign-a-unique-random-number-to-each-row)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be updating every row in your table with a random number in a particular range. You don't need to do any of the PHP processing at all.

You can simply update the table with

```
update person set person_url = (cast(rand()*89999999 as signed)+10000000);
```

You run the risk of getting duplicate entries in the person_url field which you will need to resolve by some means.

One means of doing this is to set the `person_url` column to unique and use the query with `ignore` and a different `where` clause:

```
update ignore person set person_url = (cast(rand()*89999999 as signed)+10000000)
    where person_url is null;
```

This will probably do the job in one pass, but if it doesn't, run it repeatedly until it does. You'd be very unlucky to have to use more than two or three passes and it's still likely to be much faster than manually checking for uniqueness with PHP.

Comment: His code makes sure it doesn't create any duplicate `person_url`. Yours doesn't.

Comment: feels like a one of job, so i would just add a unique key, change the above to check if person_url has been created, then just run it a few times by hand, it will fail when it hits a duplicate, but do it manually a few times and it should fill in all the values

Comment: I tried your answer but getting a MySQL error.  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'integer)+10000000)' at line 1

Comment: Use `FLOOR()` instead of `CAST()`.

Comment: My mistake - should have used `cast(??? as SIGNED)` rather than `cast(??? as INTEGER)`. `FLOOR()` is probably a better option than `CAST()` anyway. (Thanks @Barmar)

Comment: It worked, thank you. I first chose @Barmar's answer as an accepted answer, now I change it to this answer because it worked faster. No offense, please. Both answers are correct and can be used to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Prepare the statements outside the loop and use bound parameters.

```
$sql1 = $sqli->prepare("SELECT person_url FROM person WHERE person_url = ?");
$sql1->bind_param('s', $rand);
$sql2 = $sqli->prepare("UPDATE person SET person_url = ? WHERE person_id = ?");
$sql2->bind_param('si', $rand, $a);
for ($i = 0; $a < 200000; $a++) {
    $rand = mt_rand(10000000, 99999999);
    // checks whether the same url exists or not
    $sql1->execute();
    $sql1->store_result();
    if($sql1->num_rows == 0) {
        $sql2->execute();
    }
}
```